# What am I doing wrong with '--allow-fs-read=*'? Getting 'zsh: no matches found' error on Mac using Node.js Permission Model

Tags: node.js, macos, permissions, file-permissions, macos-mojave

I am experimenting with the new [Nodejs permission model](https://nodejs.org/api/permissions.html#file-system-permissions) on MacOS Venture 13.3.1. I have got Node.js v20.1.0 installed, and whenever I enter the following command:

```
node --experimental-permission --allow-fs-read=* index.js
```

I get the following error in the terminal:

```
zsh: no matches found: --allow-fs-read=*
```

I don't know what is wrong with "--allow-fs-read=*". It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve it. To get it to work, I escaped the wildcard(`*`) with a backslash( `\` ):

```
node --experimental-permission --allow-fs-read=\* index.js
```